# Skip projects with ant iterate-projects

Tags: ant

We have an ant build script which contains this bit:

```
<target name="test">
  <antcall target="iterate-projects">
    <param name="test-depends" value="false" /> 
    <param name="target" value="test" />
  </antcall>
</target>
```

I'd like to skip testing some of our projects, since they are very large and contain 3rd party tests. Something like

```
if (library.name().startsWith("lucene"))
  continue
```

How would I implement this in ant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use such technique:

```
<target name="lucene" unless="skip_test">
...
</target>
```

To skip the target you have to define property

```
<target name="test">
  <property name="skip_test" value="true"/>
  <antcall target="iterate-projects">
    <param name="test-depends" value="false" /> 
    <param name="target" value="test" />
  </antcall>
</target>
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution (I know nothing about Ant). What goes inside the '...' ?

I don't want to define a separate target for lucence, I want my main test target to just skip lucene projects.

Comment: I expect that you have a "lucene" task. If you can modify it and add 'unless="skip_test"' part, that my example will work.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ant Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) project contains useful but crude control flow tasks, including `<if>`. You could probably string that together with the other tasks in the library to achieve hat you need.